# label with url in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Here's my code:

```
<v-checkbox
    :label="I agree with the Privacy Policy"
    v-model="agree2"
></v-checkbox>
```

and I want to have an action when I click Privacy Policy. I know I can put an url there, but I would rather show model with Vue. How can I do that?

Comment: A div that shows up via `v-if="agree2"`? Or a `@change` event on the checkbox itself?

Comment: @ceejayoz no, the checkbox is for an user to accept privacy policy. I want to show up modal if he want's to read it.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/examples/modal.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the slot with name 'label' and put into whatever any you wont:

```
<v-checkbox ...>
    <div slot='label'>I agree with the <myLinkComponent>...</...></div>
</v-checkbox>
```

You can see that from documentation: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/checkboxes/#label-slot